# hiding contents of the URL in struts

Tags: java, struts2

I want to hide the parameters which are attached in my url .
My action is being hit from another website (URL redirection)

```
https://myserver/web/myaction.do?username=jhon&password=1234
```

on this action I simply redirect to a jsp

```
<action name="myaction" class="ncom.company.project.Head">
<result>/pages/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
</action>
```

on my jsp username and password are visible , i want to hide them

Comment: Are they visible _in_ the url or _on_ the rendered JSP page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you mean the parameters should not be visible in the URL, right? If so, you should do a real redirect, what you're doing is a actually forward.

In Struts 2 you'd use the "redirect" result type to send the redirect to the browser. The parameters should still be in your session/action context.

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest that you use a POST request. As far as I can see from your question you're sending a GET request. That's why you can see the parameters in the URL. I don't think this is a struts-specific problem. It's part of HTTP. Just make the other website to use a POST request. 
You might wanna take a look [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1.1) too to find out the usage of both methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things here either the one like redirect but in that case it means creating a new request object and a new action instance in value-stack.

I believe that once application hits the `myaction` and once you have done the work you can use `redirectAction` by passing any any parameters you need (if any).

But just be clear that even redirectAction will create a new Request Cycle you can use redirectAction like

```
<action name="myaction" class="ncom.company.project.Head">
 <result type="redirectAction">
         <param name="actionName">redirectAction</param>
          // any parameter you want
      </result>
</action>
 <action name="redirectAction">
       <result>/pages/HelloWorld.jsp</result>
 </action>
```

here are more details for the redirectAction
[Redirect Action](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/redirect-action-result.html)

hope it will help you

Comment: Even if i user the following
    <result type="redirectAction">
         <param name="actionName">redirectAction</param>
          // any parameter you want
    </result>

my parameters are visible

Comment: I mean all the parameters that i am parsing are visible on the address bar .

Comment: show you action class code? parameters you will pass as `<param>` will be visible in the address bar even if you use `actionRedirect`.Why you want to pass those parameters to next action?

Comment: :i am sorry . but these parameters are required at all the pages.
let me explain 
i receive the request from another website , on this website i need to check if the referrer is valid , then i need the user to input a password which i verify on the basis of the parameters i received on the request .
my goal is to hide these parameters from address bar

thanks

Comment: OK!! But if you need these parameters throughout application than its always better to set them say in `session` or in any other scope  and when you need them you can refer to them.since one option is to set them at each `request` but that will not be a good way to set them at each `request`